# createObject of vbs vs Activator.CreateInstance of C#

Tags: c#, vbscript, activex, createobject

I need to convert a vbs to C# application

The vbs contains the creation of a new object and it works

```
Set dllApp = CreateObject("MGCPCBReleaseEnvironmentLib.MGCPCBReleaseEnvServer")
```

I read that by using Activator.CreateInstance I can have the same result (if not please explain).

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MGCPCBReleaseEnvironmentLib.MGCPCBReleaseEnvServer");
dynamic m = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

When i run this code there is an exception:

retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID ... failed due to the following error: ... Class not registered

When I run the vbscript on the same machine it works fine. What is the difference between the C# implementation and the vbscript implementation?

Comment: Make sure your C# app matches the bitness of the component.

Comment: What do you mean by "bitness of the component"?

Comment: I mean if the component is 32 bit then the C# app must also be 32 bit, you can't mix & match 32 & 64 bit.